# How to read the page content into a string in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, string

I would like to retrieve the content of a link (e.g. http://pastebin.ca/raw/2314500 which is a binary image) in an AJAX request. How to read the binary string in Javascript? The following code doesn't work:

```
function httpGet(theUrl)
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            return xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", theUrl, false );
    xmlhttp.send();    
}

alert(httpGet("http://pastebin.ca/raw/2314500"))
```

Comment: Why do you want to "read an image binary" with JavaScript?

Comment: i want to read it and convert binary string to a image

Comment: Why not just use `document.createElement('img').src = theUrl`?

Comment: @ExplosionPills are you sure can work? did u tried use the link and run the code? can't the link data are binary data

Comment: doesn't work,you can try run the code at here http://jsfiddle.net/anthor/9xT5B/

Comment: You have to append the image to the DOM somehow, but that URL does not appear to be a valid image...

Comment: @ExplosionPills show me the code with DOM

Comment: `var img = document.createElement('img'); img.src = theUrl; document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(img);`

Comment: i can use this link can create a .jpeg picture with python, i don't think so this is wrong binary string. this is the sample i create,still can't show the image http://jsfiddle.net/anthor/9xT5B/1/

Comment: Is it possible that the problem is cross origin policy? Javascript cannot process strings loaded from different domain. You will probably need some server side proxy so that it appears to be from the same domain.